# Following program is throwing an error related memory access

Tags: c++, templates, generics

/*This program is using template class. I don't know why but this program is throwing an error at run time related memory access violation. in below comments i will explain which line is causing this error.*/

```
#include<iostream>
    using namespace std;
    const int size =3;
    template <class t="">
    class vector
    {
        T* v;
    public:
        vector()
        {
            v=new T[size];
            for(int i=0;i<size;i++)>
                v[i]=0;
        }
        vector(T* a)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<size;i++)>
                v[i]=a[i];
        }
        T operator*(vector &y)
        {
            T sum=0;
            for(int i=0;i<size;i++)>
                sum+=this->v[i] * y.v[i];
            return sum;
        }
        void display(void)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<size;i++)>
            {
                cout<<v[i]<<"\t";
            }
                cout<<"\n";

        }
    };
    int main()
    {
        int x[3]={1,2,3};
        int y[3]={4,5,6};
        vector<int> v1;
        vector <int> v2;

        v1=x; // This is causing an error 
        v2=y; // This is causing an error
        //int R=v1*v2;
        //cout<<"R = "<<R<<"\n";
        cout<<"V1 = ";
        v1.display();
        cout<<"V2 = ";
        v2.display();
        cout<<"V1 x V2 = "<<v1*v2;
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

2 Problems:

1. You are not initializing memory for your vector
2. You are calling the constructor incorrecly

To fix #1

```
   vector(T* a)
   {
        v=new T[size];
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++)>
            v[i]=a[i];
   }
```

To fix #2

```
int x[3]={1,2,3};
int y[3]={4,5,6};
vector<int> v1(x);
vector <int> v2(y);
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is there is no `operator=(int [])` defined for `vector`.

So in other words, compiler does not know what do you mean by `v1=x` when it comes to type `int[] = vector<int>`.

You are not calling the overloaded constructor there. So you either need to call it `vector<int> v1(y);` or implement `vector::operator=(const T[] v)`;

*I hope i got the types right*

Comment: He isn't using std::vector, it is his own vector class.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem is in this constructor

```
    vector(T* a)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++)>
            v[i]=a[i];
    }
```

You did not allocate memory for the array pointed by v.

Answer (score 0):

the constructor `vector(T * a)` will get called and the member `v` is not initialized with anything. This causes undefined behavior. So to fix this you need to allocate in that constructor

```
vector(T* a)
{
    v = new T[size];//this line is new
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
        v[i]=a[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When calling the lines in question, the program is using a default assignment operator which is doing something that causes your violation. You need to implement this yourself, for example, this worked for me:

```
T& operator=(T const * a)
{
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
        v[i]=a[i];
    return *this;
}
```